# How to lock a pdf selecting text not available

Tags: python, image, pdf

I need to convert a pdf document so that the user can't select any text.
I thought about overlaying a pdf with transparent image. Is it possible in python 3 ?
Maybe just converting every page to a jpeg and then putting it all together as pdf is a better idea?

Thanks

Comment: *"overlaying a pdf with transparent image"* - user still can do ctrl-a ctrl-c, so this doesn't work. *"converting every page to a jpeg"* - this is an option but it vehemently reduces the pdf quality and keeps visually impaired people to be able to use your pdf at all.

Comment: Is there any way to protect a pdf against cp paste?

Comment: There are the encryption permissions, cf. Rob's answer. Not all programs respect these permissions, though.

Answer (score 1):

The PDF standard includes a set of access permissions that can be used (among other things) to restrict users from copying text and images to the clipboard or otherwise extracting text from the PDF. See https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/securing-pdfs-passwords.html for more information.